# Product of first n primes modulo 9 is always either 3 or 6?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Why is the product of n sequential primes seemingly always either 3 or 6?

ie:
$2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13 \cdot 17 = 510510$ and $510510 \pmod{9} \equiv 3$

$510510 \cdot 19 \pmod{9} = 3$

$9699690 \cdot 23 \pmod{9} = 6$

$223092870 \cdot 29 \pmod{9} = 3$

$6469693230 \cdot 31 \pmod{9} = 3$

$200560491030 \cdot 37 \pmod{9} = 3$

etc

So if a number * the first n primes (mod 9) isn't 3 or 6 then that number isn't the next prime?

Comment: After $2$ and $3$, any other prime is of the form $3k+1$ or $3k+2.$ You can use this observation to prove your claim.

Comment: This is true but not very useful as a proof of whether a number is prime, both because it's computationally intensive and because it essentially just checks if the number you're checking is divisible by 3 which leaves a lot more on the table in terms of checking if a number is prime (and we can also do it much, much faster anyway)

Comment: No to the second part, though. Multiplying by any number not divisible by $3$ will still give you a number that is $\in \{3,6\} \pmod9$.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers/comments! I just learnt these are called 'primorials'.

Comment: $\begin{align}{\rm Put}\,\ d=3\,\ {\rm in\!:}\ \ d^2\nmid ad\iff d\nmid a&\iff \bmod d\!:\ \ \ a\ \equiv\ 1,2,\ \ldots,d\!-\!1\\[.1em] &\iff \bmod d^2\!:\ ad\equiv d,2d,\ldots(d\!-\!1)d\end{align}\quad$

Comment: @EricSnyder But it is still true that if you get something which is not equivalent to $3$ or $6$ that the number you multiplied by must not be the next prime - in fact it must be a multiple of $3.$ It's true, but not helpful.

Comment: @StephenDonovan Excellent point. "Not the next prime" is, as you say, not very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes because the product (assuming that it contains at least 2 terms) will be a multiple of $3$ but not a multiple of $9$. So it will always be congruent to 3 or 6 (modulo 9).

Answer (score 2):

The product of the first $n$ primes (for $n>1$) is divisible by 3 but not by 9, hence it must equal 3 or 6 modulo 9.